# Is Whey Protein Bad For the Heart

Tags: cardio, hypertrophy, heart

Since the heart contains muscles....does taking whey protein increase the muscle size of the heart thus increasing the weight of the heart...so is it bad for health?

Comment: Whey protein is just made from either milk or as a byproduct of cheese making. It's just dairy. Your heart will enlarge in response to exercise in general, regardless if you use whey or not.

Comment: So is exercise bad for the heart than coz it increases heart size?

Comment: Uh...no, not as a general rule. It's a natural adaptation. Why do you think a heart that weighs more is less healthy?

Comment: Why would whey be different than any other protein?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No, whey protein is not bad for the heart.**

Two reasons for this:

1. Protein consumption alone, in the absence of significant (overload) exertion of a muscle, does not cause a muscle to grow. Additionally, in the absence of kidney disease, excessive protein consumption is not harmful.
2. An enlarged heart (cardiomegaly) may or may not indicate a problem depending on the cause. If your heart is enlarged due to participation in endurance exercise, that isn't a problem, but if your heart is enlarged because your arteries are clogged and it struggles 24 hours per day to pump blood through them, then that is a problem. And in the latter case, the enlarged heart is a *sign* of the underlying problem of arterial plaque, it is not actually a problem in itself.

Answer (score 0):

The body gets in most western countries enough protein from diet alone, excess protein will just be burnt, no matter the source of it. If your intake is far to high it may have negative health effects, no matter if its from whey or wheat. Excercise may increase heart volume, which does not have to be bad as it in this case may lower your resting pulse. If your heart is enlarged due to drug abuse or fat build up due to a terrible diet or disease, it will have negative health effects.

Answer (score 0):

The bottom line: take moderate amount of whey, don't take 10 scoops at a time as some do thinking to accelerate growth. Anything including air or water if taken in crazy amounts is not good. the mice studies they do in the labs is the equivalent like a person taking in cannisters of protein powder. They don't tell you that in their studies.